# Getting registers using ptrace in aarch64

Tags: c, arm64, ptrace

I'm attempting to use ptrace to manipulate registers on aarch64.  Looking at sys/user.h in my aarch64 toolchain (android-ndk-r10e), I see

```c
#elif defined(__aarch64__)

// There are no user structures for 64 bit arm.

#else
```

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but how do I get/set registers for an aarch64 program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct user_pt_regs` is defined in asm/ptrace.h which is (eventually) included by sys/ptrace.h.